# Plugin that grabs the coordinates of all the cities in our database

Tags: php, plugin, wordpress, geospatial

I have a plugin that grabs the coordinates of all the cities in our database working in WordPress here.

```
function findCoordinates($address) {
$latitude  = null;
$longitude = null;
if (!is_string($address)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Address must be a string");
}

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $address);

$response = json_decode(@file_get_contents($url));
if (isset($response)) {
    $result    = $response->results[0];
    $latitude  = $result->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $result->geometry->location->lng;
}

return array($latitude, $longitude);

}
function Coordinates_admin() {

$SQL = "SELECT a.*, b.name as state,b.code as state_code, c.name as country, c.iso_code as country_code From city a
JOIN state b on a.IDState = b.IDState
Join country c on b.IDCountry = c.IDCountry";

$retval = mysql_query($SQL);
if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {


    $address = $row["name"] . "," . $row["state"] . "," . $row["state_code"] . "," . $row["country"] . "," . $row["country_code"];
    list($latitude, $longitude) = findCoordinates($address);
?>
```

Now I'm working on another plugin that adds new cities to the database, and I want it to get the lat and long automatically. I successfully did this but I was told I'm just retyping code instead of using reusable code. I went through examples and tutorials and still don understand what I am doing wrong (but it works). I am very confused on this and looking for some help on how I can make this code shorter using reusable code from my previous plugin functions.

```
//add city
if(isset($_POST['Add_City'])){
//adds IDState, name and unactive for new city.
$idstate = $_POST ['idstate'];
$name = $_POST ['name'];



$SQL="INSERT INTO city (IDState, name, is_active) VALUES ('". $idstate ."','". $name ."', ' 0 ' )";
$result=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

//grabs new city id.
$cityid = mysql_insert_id();

//puts together address for that specific city.
$SQL2 = "SELECT a.*, b.name as state,b.code as state_code, c.name as country, c.iso_code as country_code From city a
JOIN state b on a.IDState = b.IDState
Join country c on b.IDCountry = c.IDCountry WHERE IDCity= $cityid";
$retval = mysql_query($SQL2);

if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {
    $address = $row["name"] . "," . $row["state"] . "," . $row["state_code"] . "," . $row["country"] . "," . $row["country_code"];
    list($latitude, $longitude) = findCoordinates($address);
    $SQL3="UPDATE city SET latitude=$latitude, longitude=$longitude WHERE IDCITY= $cityid";
    $result1=mysql_query($SQL3) or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

Comment: The function `Coordinates_admin()` ends abruptly in your sample code... Also, it's best if you indent the code nicely, it's difficult to parse it this way... What exactly is the duplicate code, `$SQL2` and the `while` loop?